# IE Stops Script Execution Using Reference to console.log/error/warn/info

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer

If you get a reference to one of the console.log (console.error console.warn console.info) functions in IE 11 and try to call it, it blows up and stops script execution *when not using F12 dev tools*.

```
const logFunc = console.log;
logFunc('do some logging'); <-- stops executing further scripts here
```

If you have dev tools showing, it works fine. So the only way to debug is the old-fashioned alert approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE must do some optimizations when you make calls to console log functions when not using their dev tools. But you can call them directly fine, and it won't stop execution:

```
console.log('log the thing');
```

But if you get a reference, it fails. So the workaround is to not use references to those functions and always call them directly. You can create wrapper functions that do this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working is,

Since version 10, Internet Explorer always has a console object. If the developer tools are closed, calls to the console object are simply ignored.

You can copy the method to a variable, but you cannot use the variable to call the method.

Reference:

[Console.log Surprises with Internet Explorer 11 and Edge](https://www.beyondjava.net/console-log-surprises-with-internet-explorer-11-and-edge)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It would be interesting to know exactly what's going on there, and why they would create an error situation rather than just silently suppressing. Just from a curiosity standpoint.